# Finding the identification topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading the book of Dugundji under Identification topology, and as stated:

Let $p: I \rightarrow {\{0\}\cup \{1\}}$ be the characteristic function on $[1/2,1]$.

Then the mapping should i think is like this:
\begin{equation*}
p(x)=\begin{cases}
      1,& x\in I\\
      0, & x\notin I
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Now the open sets in $I$, as i understood, are

$[1/2,1], \varnothing$,

$[1/2,x)$ for $\frac{1}{2}<x\leq 1$,

$[x,1)$ for $\frac{1}{2}\leq x<1$, and

$(x,y)$ for $\frac{1}{2}\leq x<y\leq 1$.

So, the images of these open sets under $p$ is 1. The mapping here is surjective. How is it that the identification topology by $p$ is
$\{\{0,1\}, \varnothing, \{0\}\}$?

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: thanks...can u take a look at my problem once more?i'd made the changes

Comment: The set $[1/2,1]$ is not open in $I$ (I assume $I$ is the unit interval $[0,1]$).

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you’ve misunderstood the definition of the map $p$. $I=[0,1]$, and $p$ is the characteristic function *of* (not *on*) $\left[\frac12,1\right]$, so

$$p:[0,1]\to\{0,1\}:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }0\le x<\frac12\\
1,&\text{if }\frac12\le x\le 1\;.
\end{cases}$$

A set $U\subseteq\{0,1\}$ is open in the identification topology generated by the map $p$ if and only if $p^{-1}[U]$ is open in $I=[0,1]$. Since $\{0,1\}$ has only four subsets, it’s easy to check them individually.

1. Of course $p^{-1}[\varnothing]=\varnothing$ and $p^{-1}[\{0,1\}]=I$ are both open in $I$, so $\varnothing$ and $\{0,1\}$ are open in the identification topology on $\{0,1\}$ (as of course they must be in order for it to **be** a topology on $\{0,1\}$).
2. If $U=\{0\}$, then $p^{-1}[U]=\left[0,\frac12\right)$, which is open in $I$, so $\{0\}$ is open in the identification topology on $\{0,1\}$.
3. Finally, if $U=\{1\}$, then $p^{-1}[U]=\left[\frac12,1\right]$, which **not** open in $I$, so $\{1\}$ is not open in the identification topology on $\{0,1\}$.

The open sets in the identification topology on $\{0,1\}$ are therefore $\varnothing$, $\{0\}$, and $\{0,1\}$. This is the so-called [Sierpiński space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) (except that the version in the Wikipedia article interchanges the points $0$ and $1$ from Dugundji’s version).